# new Date() works in Chrome but throws 'Invalid date' in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, primeng

Used ng prime datepicker in application.

Getting date in **Fri May 14 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** format as response from api.

Then converting **Fri May 14 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** this response with new Date().

Then binding the response to ng prime datepiker.

Working fine in chrome.
In firefox it is showing "Invalid date".

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [the Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date):

> A string value representing a date, specified in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method. (These formats are IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps, and also strings in a version of ISO8601.)

Since you aren't passing one of those formats, you are dependent on implementations having non-standard support for your format.

Chrome does. Firefox doesn't.

Use a date parsing library that lets you specify the format (such as [date-fns/parse](https://date-fns.org/v2.21.3/docs/parse)) or change the API so it outputs dates in [the standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0):

You can as well, use the dateStringToDate function in date-fran module. It converts date formats of the form "Fri May 14 2021" to actual date instances.